# Where is the built output from TACO remote build?

Tags: cordova, taco

This must be a stupid question. I'm using taco-cli and remotebuild to build my cordova app on a macincloud instance.

```
taco build ios
```

It works fine, I can clearly see communication between Windows and the remote agent, and it says the build has succeeded. But... where is the built output? Should it appear somewhere on my Windows machine? I've looked in platforms/ios - I was expecting to see a build folder, but there's nothing there.

Answer (score 0):

The build output should output into the command line. Maybe turn on to vebose mode? Otherwise, the build output will be stored on the Mac. in this folder with the build number. "/Users/[USERNAME]/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/[build#]/". It's a file called build.log.

Example: /Users/username/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/38631/